# How to add a certain number of space (or other characters) to a range of lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example, to add a block comment to this Nix lang snippet

```hs
 5   pythonEnv =
 6     pkgs.python38.withPackages (
 7       packages:             
 8         [ packages.django   
 9           packages.psycopg2 
10         ]                   
11     );
```

like this

```hs
 5   pythonEnv =
 6     pkgs.python38.withPackages (
 7       packages:             # |             
 8         [ packages.django   # | This is a function                      
 9           packages.psycopg2 # |                         
10         ]                   # |       
11     );
```

I would first need to add an arbitrary number of space at the end of a range of lines, to be able to make alterations with block visual selection(s). So how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I went with `:normal` (see `:help :normal`) while specifying the ranges or using visual selections of lines.

For example, to add 27 hyphens (`-`) at the end of a range of lines, enter `:5,11normal 27A-` where

- `:` - to start a command
- `5,11` - see `:help cmdline-ranges`
- `normal` - see `:help :normal`
- `27A` - Append text at the very end of the line `[count]` times. (See `:help A`)
- `-` - The string to duplicate

```
in---------------------------
  pkgs.mkShell {---------------------------
    buildInputs = [---------------------------
      pythonEnv---------------------------
    ];---------------------------
  }---------------------------
```

Or, to add the string `space` 3 times at the very beginning of the visually selected lines,

1. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to start `VISUAL LINE` mode to select the lines
2. Type `:normal 3gIspace` (see `help gI`)

```
spacespacespacein
spacespacespace  pkgs.mkShell {
spacespacespace    buildInputs = [
spacespacespace      pythonEnv
spacespacespace    ];
spacespacespace  }
```